# rails koala gem - get API url request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, koala-gem

I'm working on rails 4, with the Koala gem to retrieve users pictures from Graph API.

I can receive the gem to receive the pictures:

```
picture, picture_medium, picture_small = graph.batch do |batch_api|
  batch_api.get_picture(facebook_id, {'width' => PIC_SIZE_LARGE, 'height' => PIC_SIZE_LARGE}, 'return_ssl_resources' => '0')
  batch_api.get_picture(facebook_id, {'width' => PIC_SIZE_MED, 'height' => PIC_SIZE_MED}, 'return_ssl_resources' => '0')
  batch_api.get_picture(facebook_id, {'width' => PIC_SIZE_SMALL, 'height' => PIC_SIZE_SMALL}, 'return_ssl_resources' => '0')
end
```

but I would like to save the url the Koala is using (I preffer the user will call the url, instead of me).
I assumes that the gem calls:
    https://graph.facebook.com/facebook_id/picture

but I don't want it to be hard-coded.
Is there a way extracting the url from the gem?
thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow! What have you tried to do to find this out yourself? (so we don't duplicate any efforts you have gone to... and to show us that you have actually put in an effort yourself before asking us to do it for you :) )

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
picture, picture_medium, picture_small = graph.batch do |batch_api|
  batch_api.get_picture(facebook_id, {'width' => PIC_SIZE_LARGE, 'height' => PIC_SIZE_LARGE}, 'return_ssl_resources' => '0')
  batch_api.get_picture(facebook_id, {'width' => PIC_SIZE_MED, 'height' => PIC_SIZE_MED}, 'return_ssl_resources' => '0')
  batch_api.get_picture(facebook_id, {'width' => PIC_SIZE_SMALL, 'height' => PIC_SIZE_SMALL}, 'return_ssl_resources' => '0')
end
```

to this

```
@graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(oauth_access_token)

@graph.batch do |batch_api|
  @large_pic = batch_api.get_picture(facebook_id, {'width' => PIC_SIZE_LARGE, 'height' => PIC_SIZE_LARGE}, 'return_ssl_resources' => '0')
  @med_pic = batch_api.get_picture(facebook_id, {'width' => PIC_SIZE_MED, 'height' => PIC_SIZE_MED}, 'return_ssl_resources' => '0')
  @small_pic = batch_api.get_picture(facebook_id, {'width' => PIC_SIZE_SMALL, 'height' => PIC_SIZE_SMALL}, 'return_ssl_resources' => '0')
end
```

And then the pics in your views without saving them to the db

```
= image_tag @large_pic
```